# When decrypting in RSA using Java BigIntegers, how do I preserve a zero byte at the beginning of the original data?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, biginteger, public-key-encryption

I am implementing my own version of RSA, along with the padding scheme RSA-OAEP in Java. This is my code for the basic algorithm:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, RSA_PublicKey publicKey) {
   BigInteger message = new BigInteger(data);
   BigInteger n = publicKey.getModulus(); //RSA Modulus
   BigInteger e = publicKey.getPublicExponent(); //RSA Public Exponent
   if (message.compareTo(n) >= 0) {
       throw new InvalidDataException();
   }
   byte[] cipherText = message.modPow(e, n).toByteArray(); //Encryption
   return cipherText;
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, RSA_PrivateKey privateKey) {
   BigInteger cipherText = new BigInteger(data);
   BigInteger n = privateKey.getModulus(); //RSA Modulus
   BigInteger d = privateKey.getPrivateExponent(); //RSA Private Exponent
   if (cipherText.compareTo(n) >= 0) {
       throw new InvalidDataException();
   }
   if (cipherText.compareTo(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) == 1) {
       throw new InvalidDataException();
   }
   byte[] message = cipherText.modPow(d, n).toByteArray(); //Decryption
   return message;
}
```

In RSA-OAEP, a series of operations are performed on the data and a random seed using a mask generation function before encryption. A zero byte is placed in front of the padded data. This is what it looks like in my code:

```
buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(k);
buffer.put((byte)0);
buffer.put(maskedSeed);
buffer.put(maskedDB);
byte[] em = buffer.array();
byte[] cipherText = encrypt(em, publicKey);
return cipherText
```

When I decrypt this ciphertext, sometimes the zero byte is still in the resulting byte array, and other times it is not. For example, this data (in hex) was the same before encryption and after decryption:

00c127a743b56f53e46223eba367b63d3378648c1d5ce3e8eec1f714c099a15b674c528d5051c1c9a32dc39fb13ee745864c7f572fa950dc8336a54d89503754f6c18dd463ec1633e6e94638230d9b10cc6e2904f4c69247a8bac0c60885b37b8adefe3b682b3a6d39f445447fa2f173b408346d3d0db086e199ef9c1fd0d14f

However, this data:

001c924b794c178c9955d4f3211c67ecda59ffe8c4be55c101bcd5ff3ce0a746ca447b5fc8fd8725cbb083e4b9244cf49b6ca84465680c0c49bec2bab3dfab6371673f0d01605d641330592ffb8915229c2dc4ea1ffcdf8a9a0e461fdf224f5cf57f74affac9d35dd3ce61ff1dd068a8c9495290735415984ddb71515823f746

was decrypted as this:

1c924b794c178c9955d4f3211c67ecda59ffe8c4be55c101bcd5ff3ce0a746ca447b5fc8fd8725cbb083e4b9244cf49b6ca84465680c0c49bec2bab3dfab6371673f0d01605d641330592ffb8915229c2dc4ea1ffcdf8a9a0e461fdf224f5cf57f74affac9d35dd3ce61ff1dd068a8c9495290735415984ddb71515823f746

According to the RSA standard, the decrypted padded data is supposed to be checked for this zero byte to ensure it is properly padded, and to return an error message if it is not. I believe this has something to do with the fact that BigIntegers are signed. Is there some workaround for this issue?

Comment: *"When I decrypt this ciphertext, sometimes the zero byte is still in the resulting byte array, and other times it is not."* - Please [edit] your question to give some examples of that.

Comment: I just realized the zero byte does not appear when the first bit of the padded data after the zero byte is a 0. If it is a 1, it works fine. This definitely has to do with BigIntegers being signed.

Comment: That's what you get for doing RSA by hand. BigInteger arithmetic has no concept of how big *you* expect the answer to be. If the result is 25 your going to get one byte no matter how big the modulus is. You have to add zeros yourself. You might want to write a method that take a BigInteger and an expected length and returns a big-endian byte array of that length with zeros prepended as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`new BigInteger(data)` always parses the data in two-complement notation where the most-significant bit signalizes the sign. In RSA, all numbers are positive, so you can set the sign as `1`:

```
new BigInteger(1, data)
```

Comment: Did you do this for encryption?

Comment: I did it for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: You only need it for encryption, but it shouldn't hurt for decryption. Then I guess there is something wrong with your padding and unpadding procedure. Please include it in your question. Also, why aren't you using the available Java Standard Library which can do that?